# Is it possible to have a metric that returns an array (or tensor) rather than a number?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, metrics, tensorflow2.0

I have a neural network with an output `NxM`, where `N` is the batch size and `M` are the number of outputs where the network needs to make a prediction. I would like to compute a metric for each of the `M` outputs of the network, i.e. across all instances of the batch but separately for each of the `M` outputs, so that there would be `M` values of this metric. I tried to create a custom metric as follows.

```
def my_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    return [3.1, 5.2] # a list of dummy values
```

and then pass this metric to the list of metrics of the `compile` method of the model, then Keras outputs a number that is the average of `3.1` and `5.2` (in this case, `(3.1 + 5.2)/2 = 4.15`) rather than printing the actual list. So, is there a way of returning and printing a list (or numpy array) as the metric? Of course, in my specific case, I will not return the dummy list in the example above, but my custom metric is more complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make one metric per M.

Working code for one output:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

inputs = Input((5,))
outputs = Dense(3)(inputs)
model = Model(inputs, outputs)

def metricWrapper(m):
    def meanMetric(true, pred):
        return pred[:, m]
    meanMetric.__name__ = 'meanMetric_' + str(m)
    return meanMetric
metrics = [metricWrapper(m) for m in range(3)]

model.compile(loss='mse', metrics=metrics, optimizer='adam')
model.fit(np.random.rand(10,5), np.zeros((10,3)))
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? Are you suggesting to pass different metrics for each column of the output? I have 1 network with an `NxM` output. I am not sure how I can pass a metric for each of the `M` outputs and Keras understand that I want that with your solution. Can you provide a simple complete example that applies your solution?

Comment: But, in my case, I can potentially have `K` `NxM` outputs, even though, right now, `K=1`. How will your solution scale in the case `K > 1`? To be concrete, right now, I pass the following to my compile method `model.compile(loss={k: my_loss_function for k in Ks}, ...)`.

Comment: Pass a list of metrics for each of the K outputs. ---- Maybe you should study how to make a custom training loop with eager execution, it will be way easier to get your metrics printed in the format you want.

Comment: Are you suggesting not to use `fit`?

Comment: It's a possibility. This will give you full control of your metrics. Otherwise, you willl have to adapt to Keras output with a separate metric for each column. A list might be available in the history, though, with `history = model.fit....`

Comment: How should I exactly pass `metrics = [metric_per_M(m) for m in range(M)]` to the parameter `metrics` of the `compile` method, if I did `model.compile(loss={k: my_loss_function for k in Ks}, ...)` and `len(Ks)` can be greater than 1 and each output of the network has dimension `NxM` (as I said above)? Note that I may have other metrics (e.g. accuracy) in the `metrics` parameter of the `compile` method. Should I just do `model.compile(metrics=[metric_per_M(m) for m in range(M)]+ [other_metric])`?

Comment: You can do that, but for the `K` case, you need a dictionary similar to the loss dictionary, each entry containing a list like that. You can add the other metric like that.

Comment: I tried your solution (proposed in this answer), but, in the end, Keras only prints `other_metric` and once `my_metric` (rather than `M` times). In fact, after having called `model.compile`, `model.metrics` returns a list of only two metrics (`MeanMetricWrapper` and `other_metric`). Is it because `metrics = [metric_per_M(m) for m in range(M)]` is a list that contains metrics with the same name? Note that I needed to use `@tf.function` above the definition of `my_metric `because I have an if-else inside the body of `my_metric`, but I don't really know if this is the problem.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a very simple example where your solution works.

Comment: I see.... My answer is bad then. Keras eliminates the list, probably because of equal names.... not sure if we can rename functions.

Comment: @nbro, solved it. It's possible to rename the function, see the updated answer.

Comment: So the problem was what I was thinking. Indeed, your solution (of renaming `__name__`) now seems to work.